# Php doesn’t print out _POST method

Tags: php, html, forms

I am new to php and stackoverflow sorry.

When my HTML file opens my php file the username and password aren’t printed on the webpage

I have tried using isset and just plan out printing the $_POST

```
 <form action="*file path*">
  username: <input type="text" name="Username" value ="username">
  <br><br>
  insert: <input type="text" name="Password" value="insert">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" method = _POST>

</form>
```

That is the HTML to receive the input

And here is the PHP

```
   <h6>
   <?php echo $_POST[“username”];?>
   <?php echo $_POST[“insert”]
   <h6>
```

It is supposed to print out the username and password but ends up printing nothing

Comment: use single quotes (preference) or double quotes - not those weird ass quotes

Comment: also the key name in the $_POST array matches the name="" value - not value

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you checked whether your browser sends a POST request? Whether `$_POST` contains any other values?

Comment: The keys in `$_POST` are case sensitive as well. If your input name is "Username", `$_POST['username']` will be undefined.

Comment: And `method="POST"` in your form.

Comment: did u checked solutions,

Answer (score 3):

You are not using method in your form

This:

```
<form action="*file path*">
```

should be:

```
<form action="*file path*" method="post">
```

Second, if you are not using method in your `<form>`, you can use `$_REQUEST` to get values, like:

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

One more thing, without using method, form submission will generate query string, so you can get the data by using `print_r($_GET)` also. **[What is Query String?](https://richard.jp.leguen.ca/tutoring/soen287/tutorials/query-strings-and-forms/)**

**Sidenote:** also check your quotes here `$_POST[“username”]` and `$_POST[“insert”]` maybe its due to your editor. Index name also an issue, please use correct name of index in php, `$_POST` are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "method = _POST" from your submit input field and place method="post" in your form tag e.g

```
<form action="*file path*" method="post">
```

The name attribute is what you will use to access the form from the php end and it is advised to be in lowercase e.g

```
<input type="text" name="username" value ="Your Username">
```

In PHP, you access it like this:

```
<?php echo $_POST[“username”];?>
```